# How to edit Websphere server runtime library

Tags: websphere-7

How do I add/remove jar files to the WebSphere Application Server v7.0 library? It's not the 'Edit' button. I placed some new jar files in {WAS_HOME}/runtimes/base_v7plugins/ hoping they would be picked up on the next restart, but it didn't happen.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe IBM does not support using WAS product jar files in to the 3rd party tool. However if you can give me some more details what exactly this tool is ? and what exactly you are trying to do ?

You should not be copying all the jars file from plugins folder .

Only jar files that you can use on the client side from WAS product is from /WAS_HOME/runtimes folder.

Hope this helps.
-VT
Note: These opinions are my own .

Comment: It's actually RAD. The problem is that my RAD has more jar files attached to the WebSphere Application Server v7.0 library then my colleague's. I'd like to add the jars that I have to his RAD/WebSphere Application Server v7.0 library. How do I go about it?